# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.'sql

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myconnection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
string sqlquery = "insert into [signup] values (@charactername,@characterid,@email,@phonenumber,)";
sqlconn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@charactername", txtcharactername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@characterid", txtcharacteid.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phonenumber", txtphonenumber.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // <-- Error in this line
labmsg.Text = "User " + txtcharactername.Text + " is successfully registered";
sqlconn.Close();
```

When the program try to execute the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` I get the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.'sql

Comment: This looks very questionable `@phonenumber,)` ending in a comma.

Comment: Can you please post the `Exception` you are getting?

Comment: Your error message tell it that you put wrong syntax on your query that why `query executor` cannot run that

Comment: what should i do

Comment: bro done i gave wrong database connection string thanks

Comment: Has the problem resolved?

Answer (score 2):

You have one stray `,` after your `@phonenumber` parameter, you need to remove it as it doesn't make any sense there.

```
string sqlquery = "insert into [signup] values (@charactername,@characterid,@email,@phonenumber,)";
                                                                                           ^^
```

Although specify the type directly and use the Value property is more better than AddWithValue:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@phonenumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtphonenumber.Text;
```

[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: bro done i gave wrong database connection string thanks